# Angular 5 form not validated and submitted

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to submit a small form through Angular 5. There is a file upload field within the form. In the .ts file, I have imported the ngForm as below

```
import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';
```

and for the testing purpose, I just placed a console text in the form submission method as below:

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
console.log("form submitted !");
}
```

The form in the html view is as under:

```
<form method="post" (ngSubmit)="mydocumentFrm.form.valid && onSubmit(mydocumentFrm)" #mydocumentFrm="ngForm">
<input class="form-control-file border" type="file" id="filename" required ngModel name="filename" #filename="ngModel">
                <small class="form-text text-muted">(Image, PDF or Word doc)</small>
                <div *ngIf="mydocumentFrm.submitted && filename.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="filename.errors.required">Field is required</div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

I see that the form is not been validated if I did not select any file OR  when I clicked on the submit button by selecting an image file, the console text is not appearing. However, no error occurred at the console screen.

Comment: Second condition on logical `&&` wont be executed if first evaluates to `false`. That is the reason, `onSubmit()` is not firing when form has errors. Your condition is perfectly fine, call `onSubmit` only when form is `valid`.

Comment: Have you tried `reactive form` instead of `Template-driven`?

Comment: @ShashikantDevani Why you need reactive forms for this?

Comment: Using reactive form you can archive validation easily.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I tried by omitting the first condition mydocumentFrm.form.valid and implement *ngIf="filename.hasError('required')" however, the form submitted without upload file. any suggestion?

Comment: In my first comment, I also said that your conditions are perfectly fine. You will fire `onSubmit()` only when `form` is completely `valid`.

Comment: @AmitChigadani But why the validation error is not showing? Is my validation code fine?

Comment: It does show valiadtion `errors`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/haserror-forms?file=src/app/app.component.ts Your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove mydocumentFrm.form.valid from (ngSubmit) line. rewrite this like (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(mydocumentFrm)"

Comment: What about the validation then?

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable your button and verify if form is valid in your ts file.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [disabled]="!mydocumentFrm.valid" type="submit">Upload</button>
```

In yours ts file :

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
        console.log("form submitted !");
    }
}
```